# Saving file in Chromium activates launcher

Tags: launcher, chromium

Whenever I save a file in Chromium, the launcher is activated and the Chromium logo shakes around indicating a new window has opened. In doing so it takes the focus off of the newly launched save file window. This makes it impossible to use `alt` + `s` to save the file. I find this rather frustrating as this is a shortcut I use often. Is there a workaround for this problem?